# Python Selenium dynamic condition

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, automation

I'm doing automation with selenium but I'm having trouble finding an element. I really thought this is because dynamic elements. Sometimes it displays "You found 0" or "You found 1".
Here is the html code
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk4tO.png)
Here is my code right now about it

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='swal-text' and (contains(text(),'You found 4'))]").is_displayed()
if (ele):
    print("4 ")
else:
    pass
```

The error says if it's not found, can you help me guys, please
Python 3.9.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. Code includes HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried finding the element by class name?
In your case that would be

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_class_name('swal-text')
```

Comment: It's still the same, but what makes me confused, it works if it's just looking for the class

Comment: but it's different when i add (contains(text(),'You found 4'))

Comment: @ReyhanFikri That's probably because your locator is looking for an element that contains the text, "You found 4" but it doesn't always find '4'... sometimes it finds '1', sometimes it finds '0', etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a better xpath such as `//div[@class='swal-modal']/div[@class='swal-text']` for starters.

the problem is your contains is overly strict.
Even this would be "better": `ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='swal-text' and (contains(text(),'You found '))]").is_displayed()`

If you could programatically determine the number expected you could inject that like any other string concatinations:

```
expected_value = 4
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='swal-text' and (contains(text(),'You found " + expected_value + "'))]").is_displayed()
```